# Using ASPX Receive "Could not load type" Error While Using CodeBehind

Tags: c#, asp.net, visual-studio, code-behind

When browsing to the save.aspx page, I'm receiving a "Could not load type" error message when using the CodeBehind="..." instead of CodeFile="...".  I would like to use the CodeBehind designation, because all of the assemblies are stored in the bin folder.  When I switch to CodeFile, i'm unable to reference other classes in other folders, unless i copy the .dll and classes into the "savetoken" folder every time i run the website.  The "savetoken" folder is a virtual directory, and I converted it to an application in IIS.

While using the CodeBehind designation, I want to correct this problem without copying the assemblies from wwwroot\bin to wwwroot\savetoken\bin.  Is there a way to configure the wwwroot\savetoken\web.config to point to the wwwroot\bin assemblies?

```
<%@ Page Language="C#" AutoEventWireup="true" CodeBehind="save.aspx.cs"
 Inherits="website.savetoken.save" %>
```

[image]

Comment: it looks like I will need to deploy the entire project to the GAC, because the virtual directories only look within its folder for .dll files

Comment: moving the files to different folders appears to be ineffiicient

Comment: I've settled with keeping all files underneath the root of the project.  As I reflect, there shouldn't be a reason to move the files to sub folders and reference them without creating a virtual directory off the root.